# How to combine drawer layout with viewapger2 and Navhostfragment

Tags: android, kotlin, drawerlayout, android-viewpager2, android-navhostfragment

I try to combine drawer layout with viewapger2 and Navhostfragment. When I clicked the drawer layout icon, NavigationView (that include my menu and header) is opened. whenever ı try to select one item from drawer layout , ı cant select because drawer layout is automatically close. How can ı fix this problem.

this is my `activity_main.xml`

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav" />


    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

`fragment_view_pager.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/beach4"
android:id="@+id/cons"
tools:context=".view.ViewPagerFragment">

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cons"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_pager_selector"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="@dimen/tab_padding_end"
    app:tabPaddingStart="@dimen/tab_padding_start"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`NavHeader.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:background="#B3F6FF">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mustafa"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`nav_menu`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/firstItem"
    android:title="First Item"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/secondItem"
    android:title="Second Item"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/thirdItem"
    android:title="Third Item"/>
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    companion object {

        var globalList = ArrayList<Float>()
        var globalVar3=1
        var globalVar = 1
        var globalVar2 = 1
        lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
        lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle
        lateinit var navVieww: NavigationView

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        sharedPreferences =
            this.getSharedPreferences("com.mustafa.horizontalrecycler", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        
        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this@MainActivity,
            drawer_layout,
            R.string.Open,
            R.string.Close
        )
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        val navView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navView)
        navVieww = navView
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.firstItem -> {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "First Item Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    println("First Item")
                }
                R.id.secondItem -> {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Second Item Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    println("Second Item")
                }

                R.id.thirdItem -> {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Third Item Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }
            true

        }
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            globalVar3= globalVar3+1
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }


}
```

`viewPagerFragment.kt`

```kotlin
    class ViewPagerFragment : Fragment() {

    private val args by navArgs<ViewPagerFragmentArgs>()
    private lateinit var wordViewModel: WordViewModel
    var number = 1
    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println("VieewPagerOncreated")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false)
        wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)
        wordViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            //println(it.size)
        })



        number = sharedPreferences.getInt("pageNumber", 1)
        println(number)

        val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)
        val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.view_pager)

        val fragments1: ArrayList<Fragment> = arrayListOf(
            WeatherListFragment(),
            Location1Fragment(),
            Location2Fragment(),
            Location3Fragment()

        )
        val fragments2: ArrayList<Fragment> = arrayListOf(
            LocationAddFragment()
        )


        //(i in number..x)  x sayısı locationfragment sayısından bir az olcak
        //suan için istediğimiz gibi oldu
        for (i in number..2) {
            fragments1.removeLast()
        }

        //fragments1.add(fragments2.get(0))
        val adapter =
            ViewPagerAdapter(fragments1, requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        if (MainActivity.globalVar > 1) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(args.currentPage, false)
        }

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager)
        { tab, position -> }.attach()


        // bu kod ile başlıgın ismini değiştirebiliriz
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Ingredient Display"
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.firstItem -> {
                    println("viewpagerfragment")
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "First Item Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    println("First Item")
                }
                R.id.secondItem -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Second Item Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                    println("Second Item")
                }

                R.id.thirdItem -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Third Item Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }
            true
        }
        return view
    }
}
```